# How to run a line in Powershell in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, subprocess

I have a line of Powershell script that runs just fine when I enter it in Powershell's command line. In my Python application which I run from Powershell, I am trying to send this line of script to Powershell.

```
powershell -command ' & {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg' 'C:\Images' 'W:\product_images\import'}'
```

I know that the script works because I've been able to implement it on its own from the Powershell command line. However, I haven't been able to get Python to send this line to the shell without getting a "non-zero exit status 1."

```
import subprocess

product = "765377"
scriptPath = "./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1"

def process_image(sku, fileType, searchDirectory, destinationPath, scriptPath):
    psArgs = "Process-Image '"+sku+"' '"+fileType+"' '"+searchDirectory+"' '"+destinationPath+"'"
    subprocess.check_call([create_PSscript_call(scriptPath, psArgs)], shell=True)

def create_PSscript_call(scriptPath, args):
    line = "powershell -command ' & {. "+scriptPath+"; "+args+"}'"
    print(line)
    return line

process_image(product, ".jpg", "C:\Images", "C:\webDAV", scriptPath)
```

Does anyone have any ideas to help? I've tried:

- subprocess.check_call()
- subprocess.call()
- subprocess.Popen()

And maybe it is just a syntax issue, but I haven't been able to find enough documentation to confirm that.

Comment: I bet your quoting / quote escaping is wrong somewhere - what is the output of `print(line)`?

Comment: print(line) outpout: powershell -command ' & {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg' 'C:\Images' 'C:\webDAV'}'

Comment: I'm suspicious of the original PowerShell command. It has single quote strings nested in a single quote string. I'm not surprised it doesn't work from Python - I'm surprised it ever works. `powershell -command ' & {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg'` the command content starts at `' & {` and finishes at `-Image '`

Comment: Is `Process-Image` a valid PowerShell cmdlet on your machine? Or is it a parameter to `uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1`, if the former it may not be on your path, if the latter then that semi-colon will break things.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Then how would I make `powershell -command " & {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg' 'C:\Images' 'W:\product_images\import'}"` into a string including all quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using single quotes inside a single quoted string breaks the string. Use double quotes outside and single qoutes inside or vice versa to avoid that. This statement:

```psh
powershell -command '& {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg' 'C:\Images' 'W:\product_images\import'}'
```

should rather look like this:

```psh
powershell -command "& {. ./uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1; Process-Image '765377' '.jpg' 'C:\Images' 'W:\product_images\import'}"
```

Also, I'd use `subprocess.call` (and a quoting function), like this:

```python
import subprocess

product    = '765377'
scriptPath = './uploadImageToBigcommerce.ps1'

def qq(s):
    return "'%s'" % s

def process_image(sku, fileType, searchDirectory, destinationPath, scriptPath):
    psCode = '. ' + scriptPath + '; Process-Image ' + qq(fileType) + ' ' + \
             qq(searchDirectory) + ' ' + qq(destinationPath)
    subprocess.call(['powershell', '-Command', '& {'+psCode+'}'], shell=True)

process_image(product, '.jpg', 'C:\Images', 'C:\webDAV', scriptPath)
```